# SQL Trigger Create Table statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a new table if someone inserts a value to the users table. I have a trigger :

[image: Trigger with phpmyadmin]

but it throws the error :

> MySQL meldet: #1422 - Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.

Then I tried to create it manually with begin and end statement, but it throws another error:

[image: manually trigger]

If I do the same trigger with a simple statement like `delete from users` the trigger works. Does someone know how to create the trigger with a create statement?

And optionally how to create the table name like `user_22` ( with the userid from users insert)?

Comment: Think once ... on every insert you want to create a table??? So for 10M insert you want to have 10M tables? You should consider re-designing your DB structure.

Answer (score 1):

All data definition language (DDL) statements, such as create, alter, drop, cause implicit commit of transactions, therefore they are not allowed in user defined function or triggers because these are supposed to run in the same transaction as the sql statement that invoked them. You can create a stored procedure that inserts the data in the user table and creates another table, but I would not do that either.

Moreover, you seem to have a serious design flaw: you should not create a separate table for each user. You can store user related information in a single table, where the user id will tell you which user a certain record belongs to.